# Android appcompat v7:23

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-manager

Today, Google released SDK 6 API 23+.

I tried to create a project with the API 23, but I'm having the following problem:

Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0

Here's my gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.package"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    wearApp project(':wear')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
}
```

In the SDK manager, the version 23 isn't listed to update:

[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: You should wait for a few more hours or days..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As seen in the revision column of the Android SDK Manager, the latest published version of the Support Library is 22.2.1. You'll have to wait until 23.0.0 is published.

**Edit:** API 23 is already published. So u can use 23.0.0

Comment: This is constantly going to be outdated. Is there a link that shows the most current version?

Comment: The [Support Library Revision History page](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html) always tells you the latest version.

Answer (score 48):

Original answer:

I too tried to change the support library to "23". When I changed the `targetSdkVersion` to 23, Android Studio reported the following error:

> This support library should not use a lower version (22) than the `targetSdkVersion` (23)

I simply changed:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
```

to

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
```

Although this fixed my issue, [you should not use dynamic versions](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/09/09/dont-use-dynamic-versions-for-your-dependencies/). After a few hours the new support repository was available and it is currently `23.0.1`.

---

**Pro tip:**

You can use double quotes and create a `${supportLibVersion}` variable for simplicity. Example:

```
ext {
    supportLibVersion = '23.1.1'
}

compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
compile "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}"
compile "com.android.support:palette-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
compile "com.android.support:customtabs:${supportLibVersion}"
compile "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
```

source: https://twitter.com/manidesto/status/669195097947377664

Comment: try this 
`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0' `

and do not forget to download the udpate (just available) ;)

Answer (score 7):

Ran into a similar issue using React Native

```
> Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1.
```

the `Support Libraries` are `Local Maven repository for Support Libraries`

[image]

Comment: works for me . i think it is just gradle can't find it in the jcenter repositoriy

Comment: @AlainIb enabled the highlighted "Local Maven for Support Libraries"

Comment: ok thanks. strangly it work just after re running "react-native run-android" 3 or 4 times the project and cleaning each it. it is like some time it work some time not without changing anything

Answer (score 2):

First you need to download the latest support repository (17 by the time I write this) from internal SDK manager of Android Studio or from the stand alone SDK manager. Then you can add `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'` or any other support library you want to your build.gradle file. (Don't forget the last `.0`)

Answer (score 0):

Latest published version of the Support Library is **24.1.1**, So you can use it like this,

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
```

Same as for other support components.

You can see the revisions here,
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html