# Install Android Studio on already existing SDK

Tags: android, android-studio

I downloaded AS without SDK, installed it in the 64-bit directory, while I already have Android SDK and NDK tools previously installed (they're on the 32-bit directory somehow).

I would like to know how to properly set it up, I'm asking this because I'm prompted to install the SDK tools, and I also get a `failed to resolve support library` error, but from AS settings I can see that AS recognizes the SDK already installed, is there anything I have to make sure of?

I started an empty project that has some dependencies:

`dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.+'
}`

Then I get this:
`Error:(24, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+`
And this:
`Error:(25, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:23.+`

Comment: Have you tried Tools>Android>SDK Manager>Android SDK Location: and point it in the correct directory? Do you have any more details on failed to resolve support library? Like where does it say that

Comment: @ScriptKitty See the edited post above.

Comment: @ScriptKitty And the Tools>Android>SDK Manager>Android SDK Location detects my installed SDK just right, it just complains about whitespace in the location path.

Comment: No I don't think your problem has to do with SDK. Appcompat v7 is a way to get new features onto older targets. You either didn't install it with SDK manager or your syntax is wrong give me a second

Comment: Hm it looks like your syntax is right I would recommend putting in a specific version number like `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0`. You have to install the correct package so go to tools>Android>SDK manager>launchstandalonesdkmanager button at the bottom>install packages (the ones that you target, which is API 23). This installs the latest version of the SDK

Comment: @ScriptKitty I have already API 23 installed, but I don't know much about Android support libraries, I see `Android Support Repository v30` not installed in the Extras section, should I download it?

Comment: Perhaps. Go ahead and download it. I'll be honest, when I used the support package I didn't think twice because I had installed all packages in API 23 and 22.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062460/android-appcompat-v723

Comment: @ScriptKitty I solved using the instruction in my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I moved my SDK folders to `D:/` to get rid of whitespace in the path, then I downloaded Android Support Repository v30, that solved all my problems, thanks for helping.