# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design-v7:23.0.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

I'm getting following error:

```
Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design-v7:23.0.0
```

I have updated all skd tools required (like android support library, repository) but when i sync the project it shows Error. Even on clicking "Install Repository and sync project" nothing happens.

I've checked other questions already but they did not work for me.

[image]

Comment: Try cleaning the project?

Comment: @Eenvincible Yes but doesn't work

Comment: if you updated all sdk . Try to reopen Android Studio and build your gradle again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android appcompat v7:23](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062460/android-appcompat-v723)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because it isn't called `design-v7`, but just `design` as mentioned in the [Support Library features page](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#design)

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
```