# ActivityCompat error (Cannot resolve symbol)

Tags: android, react-native

In my react-native application, I need to get location permission from the user, so I added this in one of the Activity classes...

```
public void onCreate() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
}
```

However, I get a `cannot resolve symbol error` for both `ActivityCompat` and `Manifest`.

After doing some research I found out you need to add the following to the `gradle.build` file `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'`

So I did that...

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-maps')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
}
```

But I still get the same errors. I tried `clean` still nothing. I also tried restarting Android Studio `File > Invalidate Caches/Restart`, still get the errors.

How do I fix these errors?

Comment: appcompat-v7 already includes support-v4. If you use compileSdkVersion 23, update support libs to v23.4.0.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

in gradle file set the latest API and build levels:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
```

and use

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
```

here you can use the other approach:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32062974/1979882

Comment: ok it somewhat worked, but I get an error `Failed to find Build Tools revision 25.2.2`...it says it is not available for download

Comment: Just write here the latest build tool version in Android SDK.

Comment: @Bolboa ,try 25.0.1

Comment: 1) Major version of support libraries has to be the same as compile SDK version. 2) Avoid using + when specifying dependency versions.