# error on starting android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

im a web developer and newbe to android. I just installed android studio bundle, version 2.0. In a bundle version, it supposed that all SDKs be with android studio. But when I start the program it shows the following errors:

```
Error:(23, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1
Install Repository and sync project
Show in File
Show in Project Structure dialog

Error:(24, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:23.0.1
Install Repository and sync project
Show in File
Show in Project Structure dialog
```

Any idea how to fix?

Comment: Check the Link below : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062460/android-appcompat-v723

Comment: I checked the link. But really I have no idea what's going on on android studio! I've repository installed. So why im getting those errors?

Comment: download the latest sdk from sdk manager and try to add compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1' to your build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Not all android SDKs are included with the Android Studio installation, just 1, try making a new project and check the `build.gradle` file to see which version you have and then modify your other project accordingly.

Otherwise just click the `install repository and sync project` blue link that gradle is showing in the console. That will automatically install the SDK you need.